# Is it possible for dialog gauge to track an install

Tags: scripting, dialog

I'm currently using the --gauge option of dialog to increment a progress bar as a few tasks are completed eg:

```
( 
  echo 20; echo "XXX"; echo "Task 1"; echo "XXX" ; #Task 1 here
  sleep 2 ; 
  echo 40; echo "XXX"; echo "Task 2"; echo "XXX" ; #Task 2 here
  sleep 2 ; 
  echo 60; echo "XXX"; echo "Task 3"; echo "XXX" ; #Task 3 here
  sleep 2 ;  
  echo 80; echo "XXX"; echo "Task 4"; echo "XXX" ; #Task 4 here
  sleep 2 ; 
  echo 100; echo "XXX"; echo "Task 5"; echo "XXX" ; #Task 5 here
) | dialog --gauge "Performing Tasks" 6 50
```

What I also would like to do is use --gauge to show progress of a command that starts an install (sudo ./retropie_packages.sh pegasus-fe).

It seems that as I don't have individual tasks like in the above that approach will not work. I've seen pv suggested for such a thing but cannot figure out how to pipe my task through it.

Any ideas/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the correct way to do it but I ended up doing this:

```
test=0
sudo ./retropie_packages.sh pegasus-fe |
while IFS= read i; do
((++stepscomplete))
percentcomplete=$((stepscomplete*3))
if [ $percentcomplete-lt 100 ]
then
echo $percentcomplete| dialog --hline "  TEXT  " --backtitle "TESTING..." --gauge "Installing Pegasus" 6 50
else
echo 100 | dialog --hline "  TEXT  " --backtitle "TESTING..." --gauge "Installing Pegasus" 6 50
fi
done
```